# How to save csv file to specific folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I want to read each head of each column (A=77.34, B=78.28, C=85.44 and D=92.46 in this case) and to save the DataFrame. If all these heads are greater than 65, save as csv file to specific folder (High). If low than 55, save as csv to specific folder (Low).
I can't see any csv file in the folder (High in this case), and i don't understand where is my problem. I am using Python27.

My program:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import csv

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [77.34, 44.09, 44.15, 43.61],
                   'B': [78.28, 46.28, 46.00, 46.03],
                   'C': [85.44, 41.89, 42.15, 42.65],
                   'D': [92.46, 42.22, 42.55, 42.02]
                  }, index=pd.Index(range(4), name='idx'))

X1=df.iloc[0,0]
X2=df.iloc[0,1]
X3=df.iloc[0,2]
X4=df.iloc[0,3]

def Rho (df): 
    if  (X1>65 and X2>65 and X3>65 and X4>65):
        df.to_csv('High.csv')
        path = 'D:\My_Path\High'
        extension = 'csv'
        os.chdir(path)
    elif (X1<55 and X2<55 and X3<55 and X4<55):
        df.to_csv('Low.csv')
        path = 'D:\My_Path\Low'
        extension = 'csv'
        os.chdir(path)        
    else:
        print("Ignore")       
Rho (df)
```

Comment: You need to not to change the path of current working dir. `df.to_csv(os.path.join(dir,file_name))`

Comment: @Thunderwood, No, the program doesn't print "Ignore".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `to_csv` the wrong way. You can pass it the full path, including the dir, filename and extension with the `path` argument. You also don't need to change your current dir with `os.chdir(path)`.

See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```
...

def Rho (df): 
    if  (X1>65 and X2>65 and X3>65 and X4>65):
        df.to_csv(path='D:\My_Path\High.csv')
    elif (X1<55 and X2<55 and X3<55 and X4<55):
        df.to_csv(path='D:\My_Path\Low.csv')        
    else:
        print("Ignore")       
...
```

Answer (score 2):

using `df.to_csv(path="xxxx")` does not work anymore.

According to the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) you either us:

```
from pathlib import Path  
filepath = Path('folder/subfolder/out.csv')  
filepath.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  
df.to_csv(filepath)
```

OR

```
import os  
os.makedirs('folder/subfolder', exist_ok=True)  
df.to_csv('folder/subfolder/out.csv')
```

Thanks!

Comment: This method works for me.